# AS3, Flash - Call a function in a class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to call a function which is set inside a class..

How can I call that?

Here is my source, and I would like to call 'processLogin' from outside this class.
Link to source: http://pastebin.com/aFygyXKZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new instance of your class main.

Try

```
var m:main = new main();
m.processLogin();
```

Also, AS3 best practices state that classes should begin with an Uppercase letter.

You also should extend Sprite instead of MovieClip for DisplayObject classes that do not need timeline functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are only going to have one instance of the class main in your application, what you can do is:

1. Implement class main as a [singleton class](http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_singletons.html), in which case you
   can access the processLogin method using
   `main.getInstance().processLogin` or
2. Just add a public static
   variable to your main class containing the instance of your main
   class. In this instance your code would look something like:

   ```
   package actions {
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.events.*;
   import flash.net.*;
   import flash.text.*;

   public static var instance:main;

   public function main(){
   instance = this;
   }

   //The rest of your main class code...
   }
   ```

   That way, you can access your processLogin function using `main.instance.processLogin()`.

However, if your application is set to possibly have more than one instance of your main class, then the best approach would be to instantiate main and use that instance, as f-a suggested.